# Using glLoadMatrixf with my own matrix

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix

I have a simple drawing loop where I manipulate the camera, using glRotatef and glTranslatef then I attempt to draw a an object with my own matrix instead of using the gl* commands

e.g.

```
void GLCore::render()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glRotatef(camera.xRot,1.0,0.0,0.0);
    glRotatef(camera.yRot,0.0,1.0,0.0);
    glTranslatef(-camera.position.X, -camera.position.Y, -camera.position.Z);
    glPushMatrix();
    drawScene();
    glPopMatrix();
    camera.updateCamera();
}

void GLCore::drawScene()
{
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadMatrixf(mapObject->matrix.getMatrixPointer());
    glVertexPointer(....);
    glDrawElements(....);
    glPopMatrix();
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
}
```

The Matrix is from mapObject as:

```
        float m[] = { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
                0.0f, 0.0f, -10.0f, 1.0f };
```

This draws as expect, with the model 10.0f away, however when I use glLoadMatrix I loose control of the camera, the view is fixed in the initial state. This doesn't happen when I move the object using glTranslate, everything works fine and the camera will still look around. From what I understand the glLoadMatrix call should only be applied to the top matrix in the stack so it shouldn't effect the camera matrix.

Any ideas? :(

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`glLoadMatrix` assigns your matrix to the top of the stack. What you want to do is to *multiply* your matrix with the one on the top of the stack. Use `glMultMatrix` for that.

Comment: Thanks :D, that was the problem, I assumed by assign to the top of the stack it would overwrite the matrix you just pushed and its transformations would automatically be applied. I'll make this as the answer as soon as stack overflow will let me :)